# How to use method result properly in Java

Tags: java, coding-style

I will use result of a method call in some calculation. I have two ways:

1. Invoke method once and store the return into a local value, then use the local value in some calculation.
2. Use call method many times.

*Please see my sample code:*

```
public class TestMethod {

    public void doSomething_way1() {

        String prop1 = this.getProp1();
        if (prop1 != null) {
            String value = prop1 + " - another value";
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }

    public void doSomething_way2() {

        if (this.getProp1() != null) {
            String value = this.getProp1() + " - another value";
            System.out.println(value);
        }   
    }

    public String getProp1() {
        return "return the same value";
    }
}
```

NOTE that, the method doSomething will be invoked a lots at a time ( In web environment )

Can someone show me which way I should use in the case the result of method will be used at least 3 times?

Comment: Essentially no performance benefit, it expresses a specific intent that may or may not be true, and it makes changing the method to have different behavior more confusing. Call the method.

Comment: If you call the method multiple times it might have changed data in the meanwhile. If this is something you want to avoid, store it in a local variable. If you just want the same value each time: why bother calling it multiple times? Just store it in a variable. Certainly in more complicated methods it will have a performance difference (not in your example though).

Comment: Is the method idempotent?

Comment: As long as `getProp1` doesn't do something resource intesive, like contact a webservice to get the `String` I would stick with the second method.

Comment: I mean, this would depend entirely on what the method does and what you need.

Comment: Yes. The method return the same values!

Comment: If I call method manytimes. The JVM must create stack many times. So is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

I believe using the method call many times is more intuitive and makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it wont matter even if you give call to the `getProp1()` method multiple times. Because it does not perform any computation, object creation or I/O operation which may cause performance issues.

Comment: But if I call method manytimes. The JVM must create stack manytimes. So is it ok?

Comment: Not an issue. If you just run a small performance test with both the approaches, you will hardly see any difference in the outcome

Comment: I agree with Ankur here - I like calling the method once for style reasons, but, if the implementation of the method is efficient, you don't need to worry about the overhead of extra method calls; it's completely trivial for all but the most demanding, performance-critical applications. (and in those cases, the JDK may optimize and inline the method call anyway.) ALWAYS favor clean code over premature optimization. Computers get faster every year, but programmers don't get any smarter.

Answer (score 0):

You could go a step further:

```
public void doSomething_way2() {

    if (this.getProp1() != null) {
        System.out.println(this.getProp1() + " - another value");
    }

}
```

If the method is getting called a lot (I mean many, many times a second), creating the extra variable could change performance a tiny bit with respect to garbage collection and what not... I think its trivial.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, getting the value more than once could raise thread-safety issues, if the value weren't `final`, whereas if you fetch the value once, at least the entire operation of `way1` will be consistent with a single value for prop1.

But even if threading weren't an issue, I still think it's better, stylistically, to 'cache' the value in a local variable which is well named.

(I'm assuming that your real code does something more significant than return the fixed String "something") - the `getProp1` method *as written* is pretty thread-safe. :)

Comment: Use local variable is good. But what about if I only invoke method TWO time?

Comment: If the program is single-threaded, (or if you know the value will always be the same e.g. a getter for a `final` property) then maybe you don't need to bother. But in the *general* case, you never know when code might be re-used other than where you originally expected it to be, and today's single-threaded code might become tomorrow's multi-threaded logic-bomb. For me, I still would probably use a local.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance standpoint, at least from the examples given, it does not appear to be any fundamental difference doing it one way or another.  Object allocations for small numbers of iterations (unless they are heavyweight objects) should be minimal.

However, from a programming design and implementation standpoint, it may be helpful to keep the program 'cohesive', i.e. have classes more closely represent things.

In which case the local variable from the return of the method (as it is a different 'thing') and subsequent calculation.

e.g.:

```
interface Dog{
    void wagTail();
    Dung eat(DogFood f);
}

interface Human{
    void pickUpDung(Dung d);
}

codeLoop(Human m, Dog d, DogFood f){
      d.wagTail();
      Dung poo = d.eat(f);
      m.pickUpDung(poo);
}
```

whereas a less cohesive example would be

```
interface Dog{
    void wagTail();
    void eatAndHaveHumanPickUp(DogFood f);
}
// you can fill in the rest...
```

it wouldn't follow the principle of cohesion, because you wouldn't normally expect a dog call to have this kind of method...